# Search a Json directory using python

Tags: python, json, directory

I have a Json file created that holds a specific directory. I am trying to write something that will allow the user to go in and out of each "folder" creating almost a command line "file explorer"

my json file is formatted as such:

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "somefile.cmd",
                    "path": "C:\\some\\directory\\somefile.cmd",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "name": "otherfile.ps1",
                    "path": "C:\\some\\directory\\somefile.ps1",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "name": "somefile.exe",
                    "path": "C:\\some\\directory\\somefile.exe",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "name": "somefile",
            "path": "C:\\some\\directory",
            "type": "folder"
        },
        {
            "children": [
.
.
.
```

My function I am using

```
def search_json(filename):
    json_file = open(filename)
    data = json.load(json_file)
    subsyst_count = 1
    subsyst_list = []
    #list of subsystems
    for i in data['children']:
        print(subsyst_count, i['name'])
        subsyst_list.append(i['name'])
        subsyst_count = subsyst_count + 1
    user = int(input('Which Subsystem?'))
    #search json for children of subsyst_list[user]
    print(subsyst_list[user])
    for i in data['children']:
        if i['name'] == subsyst_list[user]:
            print(i['name'])
            for j in i['name']:
                print(j[0])
```

I expect it to go into the first children folder count all the folders under it and prompt user to select a number as to which subsystem to go into. I then wanted it to search that new "children" subsystem directory and again number which file to go into or file to select. instead it throws a keyerror when I have

```
   print(j['name'])
```

and then the function just spells the name of the subsystem when I have:

```
   print(j['0'])
```

Comment: `for j in i['name']` is iterating through the letters of the "name" field value. Presumably you want `i['children']`?

Comment: You'd be a lot better off refactoring this code though. I'd separate out opening the file and reading the data into a dict, and then make the navigation part recursive - pass in the dict to a function that prints children and prompts, and then calls itself with the children node that was chosen.

Comment: @Blorgbeard you are my hero